# How to generate SQL schema from Perl DBIx::Class files?

Tags: sql, perl, dbix-class

Please show me how to generate SQL schema from my Perl [`DBIx::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass) files ?

Basically the reverse of make_schema_at in [`DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema%3a%3aLoader).

I have already built the Perl schema files, I just wish to recreate the schema in my SQL database.

I can't seem to find examples going from Perl -> SQL.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`deploy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema#deploy) and [`deployment_statements`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema#deployment_statements) functions in [DBIx::Class::Schema](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema).

```
my $statements = $schema->deployment_statements;
print "$statements\n";
```